# Edit multiple records in one template

Tags: django, forms

I'm not at all sure that my approach to this problem is valid, so I'll appreciate "strategic" recommendations. From the other hand I hope to get some educational value from resolving the problem as it is.
I have a model Record and I want to edit values of several instances of it at once, on the same page.
[That is ~how my edit form should looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPWuL.png)
For that I created this template:

```
     **template.html**
     #with some omissions
     {% for record in records %}

        <td>
            <input type ="text"
                   name="position_for_record_{{ record.id}}"
                   value ="{{ record.position }}"
                   size ="3">
         </td>
         <td> 
            <input type ="text"
                   name="hours_for_record_{{ record.id }}"
                   value = "{{ record.hours }}"
                   size ="3">
         </td>
             <td>
                <input type ="text"
                       name="tips_for_record_{{ record.id}}"
                       value = "{{ record.tips }}"
                       size ="3">
             </td>
     {%endfor%}
```

After submitting this form I'll get all those fields in the request.POST, the question is how to extract them? I can, of course, iterate through ALL records

```
**views.py**

def form_returns_here(request):
    all_records=Record.objects.all()
    for record in all_records:
        if   "position_for_record_"+str(record.id) in
                                    request.POST:
```

But it just doesn't seem right.
Thank you.

Comment: Have a look at Formsets.

Comment: @voodoo-burger as I understand FormSets(after reading the docs), they are good for creating new records, possibly with some default values. But how to use them to edit data?

Comment: The Admin's TabularInline uses Formsets for both creating and updating instances so they are definitely not just for creating.

Comment: @voodoo-burger Yep, you are right - it is possible. However, it takes overriding methods of Admin model, which is out if my league for a moment. Will have to go with my "crouch"-like approach. Thanks!